# How much is the minimum safe distance between two planes in-flight?

Tags: faa-regulations, safety, air-traffic-control, separation, flying-in-formation

According to **FAA regulations**, how far should a commercial jet be away from another plane in-flight?

[image: commercial jet img]

How about military planes? They get really close when in formations... Is there a minimum distance?

[image: Military formation img]

Comment: formation flight is a different beast than normal individual flights

Comment: In the 2nd picture, though the planes appear very close to each other, but that is because of the picture. In reality, planes flying in formations like this do not flight exactly on the same level. For example, [see this picture](http://www.alaska-in-pictures.com/data/media/20/military-jet-cockpit_4483.jpg), the planes following are higher.

Comment: @Farhan Not always true. There are different formations used in different scenarios, and sometimes vary to accomodate aircraft-specific characteristics. Some patterns with some aircraft are same-level. (Not necessarily in that particular picture though.)

Comment: [Check out this Episode of Air Crash Investigation.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LN_aqPSGTCQ) It is about a mid air collusion caused by pilots not following ATC's directions. Though the crash took place on non US soil there is some information about flight separations during cruise and approach.

Comment: [Also check out this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVydZMKgST8)

Comment: @Farhan Even if the planes are at different levels in that particular formation, they're still very close both laterally and vertically. And I've certainly been at airshows where the commentator has remarked that the planes performing some stunt are within a couple of metres of each other.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey: I love your typo! Mid air collusions make me ponder the possibility of pilots secretly communicating vile schemes without ATC knowing about it...

Comment: @RobVermeulen Hmm... So, do we now need to investigate whether Trump Force One and any Russian government aircraft were in nearby airspace during the election? ;)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The question specifically asks about FAA regulations, so I will try to provide specific citations.

### Summary

For a commercial airliner (as the question asked), separation will *usually* be at least **3 miles laterally**, *or* **1,000 feet vertically**. In the enroute environment -- at higher operating speeds above 10,000 feet and based on the type of Radar and distance from the antennae -- a **5 mile** rule is applied laterally. This is true in *most but not all* situations. There are exceptions: see below.

Note also the "or": it is allowed (and in fact rather common) for two jets to cross paths at the same moment, with one 1,000 feet directly above the other. The 3 miles is only required if the jets do not have at least 1,000 feet of vertical separation.

### Pilots

The regulations do not set a specific distance that pilots flying under VFR must maintain from each other. There's just the following blanket statement:

[§91.111, Operating near other aircraft](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=d2302efbd7d0368b9999a00eba1d3f0a&node=14:2.0.1.3.10.2.4.6&rgn=div8): (a) No person may operate an aircraft so close to another aircraft as to create a collision hazard. (b) No person may operate an aircraft in formation flight except by arrangement with the pilot in command of each aircraft in the formation.

In addition, there is the catch-all "careless or reckless operation" clause:

[§91.13, Careless or reckless operation](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=d2302efbd7d0368b9999a00eba1d3f0a&node=14:2.0.1.3.10.1.4.7&rgn=div8): No person may operate an aircraft in a careless or reckless manner so as to endanger the life or property of another.

Pilots flying under IFR are subject to the same kinds of rules, and are still responsible for maintaining separation from other traffic when in visual conditions. The rules are the same: the pilot is given the discretion of deciding what a "safe distance" is.

Actual distance limits only come into play for the air traffic controllers, who are responsible for providing minimum separation distances between IFR traffic.

### Air Traffic Controllers

The set of FAA regulations for air traffic controllers is [FAA order 7110.65](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/ATC/index.htm). These regulations are quite complicated and there are lots of exceptions and corner cases for various scenario. I'll try to give only the most basic rules here, but note that a full reading of 7110.65 would be necessary to understand all the minutiae.

Vertical separation:

- [4-5-1 Vertical Separation Minima](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/ATC/atc0405.html#atc0405.html.1). In general, 1,000 feet for IFR traffic (with exceptions).
- [7-7-3 Separation](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/ATC/atc0707.html#3oJ190JACK), [7-8-3 Separation](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/ATC/atc0708.html#MpJ186JACK), [7-9-4 Separation](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/ATC/atc0709.html#rpJ398JACK). 500 feet for VFR aircraft (with exceptions).

Lateral separation:

- [5-5-4 Minima](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/ATC/atc0505.html#PiK190JACK). In general, 3 miles in the terminal environment and 5 miles in the enroute environment (with exceptions).

Things get more complicated in the following scenarios, and exceptions apply to them:

- Oceanic environment ([7110.65 Chapter 8](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/ATC/TOC.html#Chapter%C2%A08.%20Offshore/Oceanic%20Procedures)).
- Approach environment, especially at large/busy airports with parallel runways and special approach monitoring radar. ([7110.65 Chapter 3, Sections 9 & 10](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/ATC/TOC.html#Chapter%C2%A03.%20Airport%20Traffic%20Control-%20Terminal)).
- Nonradar environment (anytime the controller is not able to "apply radar separation") ([7110.65 Chapter 6](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/ATC/TOC.html#Chapter%C2%A06.%20Nonradar)).

For these scenarios the regulations are rather lengthy and complicated, so I would simply refer you to Order 7110.65 in general.

### Military

When flying in airspace controlled by ATC, military pilots must follow the same rules as civilian aircraft. ATC will keep them separated according to the rules above. However, there are two main exceptions to this.

When flying in formation, such as for training, aerial refueling, or intercepting aircraft, they are much too close for ATC to provide safety. In these cases, ATC will allow the pilots to fly under MARSA ([Military Assumes Responsibility for Separation of Aircraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MARSA_%28aviation%29)). In the case of interception, if the fighter pilot is not able to see the aircraft they are intercepting before the minimum separation, they must break off. They can only fly under MARSA if they can actually ensure visual separation.

The FAA can also define an MOA ([Military Operations Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_operations_area)). Once military aircraft enter this area, ATC is no longer responsible for them and they are under MARSA. When the aircraft leave the MOA, ATC resumes control. They can still be under MARSA for a formation, but ATC will keep that formation separated from other traffic.

In tactical formation flying, there is no limit. The [Blue Angels](http://www.blueangels.navy.mil/) routinely fly with [only 18" separation between the wing tip and the cockpit canopy](http://www.blueangels.navy.mil/show/faq.aspx). Combat aircraft fly a variety of different formation patterns at varying distances, and pilots are extensively trained on each pattern and what the appropriate/safe distances are. (For example, a fingertip formation allows for much closer flying than a line-abreast formation.)

Comment: Excellent answer!  I would suggest adding a paragraph about visual separation between aircraft since it is a commonly used procedure.  I would also suggest making it more clear that the 1,000 ft separation is for IFR-IFR traffic.  It is common for IFR-VFR to have 500 ft separation because that is how the "normal" flight levels are setup.

Comment: I believe the part about military only applies to US and the rules are very different in different countries.

Comment: I have a friend who was the thunder birds' commander for a few years.  You can see, in some Go Pro videos of his, that their wing-tips would actually bump into each other sometimes.

Comment: @SpongeBob There is absolutely no way they had a minor midair and kept flying. A mishap report would be filed and both crews would likely be investigated. Bumping a wingtip means that you are vertically out of position.  You should never be at or above leads altitude flying parade.

Comment: @SHAF - If you say so.

Comment: @SpongeBob "Bumping wingtips" could cause catastrophic damage and severely reduce laminar flow over the wing.  That would have unpredictable effects on the rest of the jet and lead to horrible accidents.  What you likely saw was a very tight formation with the wing and lead staggered by altutude making it appear they were touching.  The AF is more restrictive than the Navy, and if i touched a wingtip it would be an immediate knock it off, followed by a controllability check and a land as soon as possible.

Comment: @SHAF, I'm not arguing with you.

Comment: @SpongeBob Sorry, my kids are pissing me off and I'm feeling particularly combative.

Comment: @SHAF, Haha.  Fair enough.  Better take it out on me than them! (Seriously)

Comment: Would it be a normal occurrence for an intercepting fighter to not be able to see what he was intercepting outside of 3-5 miles? GA craft tend to be painted in high-vis color schemes, but I could imagine a drug run made with a 172 painted in forest camo with a sky underside. Even with radar telling you where to look, it can be difficult to spot a plane that doesn't want to be seen.

Comment: @KeithS Even in high-visibility paint, an airplane can definitely be hard to see beyond a few miles, even on a clear day. Hazy air and bright sun can make it hard to spot even close-in. But military interceptors have onboard tactical radar systems, and ATC (civilian or military) can provide intercept vectors from the ground. Your drug runner may have pretty paint, but he probably isn't going to have low-observable (stealth) technology. If he does, well, we're beyond the scope of this Q/A to be sure :)

Comment: Two planes travelling around 0.85 mach at their peak altitudes, how much time do they have to react for a 5 mile lateral gap? I am just trying to think if the gap is enough.

Comment: 0.85 mach is around 490 knots TAS at 35,000 feet. If they're closing head-on, that gives a closing speed of 980 knots, and the 5 miles will be covered in about 18 seconds. Not very much time to react, but at this point ATC has already messed up, and TCAS becomes the next line of defense: both planes will receive a TCAS RA (Resolution Advisory), and as long as both pilots respond immediately (as they are trained to do), avoidance will be successful.

Comment: You forgot RVSM for vertical separation. Above FL410 separation is 2000ft for RVSM capable aircraft. Also for non RVSM capable aircraft, vertical separation is 2000ft from FL 290 to FL 410 and 4000 ft above FL 410

Answer (score 8):

you have 3 separations for commercial flights

1. **vertical separation**: two aircrafts flying in the same direction will be separated by 2 flight levels (FLs), equivalent to 2000 ft. The intermediate FL is occupied by planes flying in the opposite direction. Each aircraft has thus 500 ft above and below the assigned altitude of free airspace.
2. **lateral separation**: the airways are defined as being 10 nautical miles wide, 5 for each side
3. **longitudinal separation**: I have no detailed information on this for the cruise, I hope someone else can fill the gap. During approach it depends on the size of the preceding aircraft.

Comment: you can write an entire book on longitudinal separation and still not be done with it: depending on whether it is radar or procedural separation, VOR, DME, Mach number tehnique, cruise or approach service. About 10 minutes or 80NM for cruising and between 2 to 6 mins or 5NM to 2.5 NM on approach is a good rule of thumb

Comment: @Radu094 Lol, absolutely true. In fact an entire book *has* been written about it... FAA Order 7110.65 :)

Answer (score 6):

With formation flights it is as close as the pilots feel comfortable with in the circumstances. On clear days and in level flight brushing wingtips is allowed as long as you don't endanger the other planes (which actual brushing would do).

For normal (commercial) flights vertical separation of 1000 feet is maintained when passing each other.

for planes incoming for landing there is [4-8 NM radar separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_turbulence#Hazard_avoidance) depending on the size and weight of the planes.

Comment: If by brushing you mean touching, then no, that's never allowed and is a great way to die.  Also, military flights routinely execute section approaches in bad weather where the wingman flies in parade and the lead shoots the approach.

Comment: I think a more precise definition to the phrase "brushing wingtips is allowed" is required here.

Comment: Yeah, I down voted your answer due to the "brushing wingtips is allowed" remark...

Answer (score 1):

Two answers here are "mostly" right, but not exact. What's relevant is IFR vs. VFR, not whether or not it's "commercial". In IFR it's 1000 ft vertically and 3 miles below 10,000 ft and 5 miles above 10,000 ft. This applies to non-commercial flights as well, such as part 91 flights, this has nothing to do with the flight being "commercial". And, a commercial flight can also be in VFR, not every commercial flight is IFR. Every airline flight is IFR (part 121), but you can't equate airline operations with commercial flights. I can do a commercial flight under VFR, and I can have the above-mentioned minimums on a non-commercial flight.

Answer (score 0):

It truly depends on your operation (IFR/VFR) - The following answer is in regard to IFR operations in class A airspace (+18,100ft)

**Below FL290 (29,000ft)**

Vertical separation of 1,000 ft is required

**Between FL290 and FL410**

Vertical separation of 2,000 ft is required... but under [RVSM (Reduced Vertical Seperation Minimus)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/separation_standards/rvsm/) regulations separation can be reduced to 1,000 feet if the aircraft is approved for RVSM operations.

**Above FL410** the minimums are bumped back up to 2,000ft regardless of RVSM approval.

See: [AC 91-85A](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/separation_standards/rvsm/documents/AC_91-85A_7-21-2016.pdf) for more information regarding RVSM