# Approaching a towered airport for landing but no specific pattern entry direction from atc

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications, approach, traffic-pattern

Here’s the scenario that happened to me -
Flying into a busy class D, I contacted tower with the usual “XYZ tower, Warrior 12345 12 to the west at 2,500 full stop with Oscar”

They respond “Warrior 12345 remain at altitude of 2,500” giving me clearance into the airspace but no specific entry to the pattern like “enter left downwind, base, etc, for rwy 29”. (Pattern altitude is 1200AGL)

Never heard again from tower as I got within ~1-2 miles of airport and frequency was completely busy and couldn’t get a word in.

What would you do until they addressed you or you could get a word in? Fly in circles a couple miles west of the airport? Continue on current heading and fly over the airport above pattern?

Thanks

Comment: What is the pattern altitude at the airport in question?

Comment: 1200 AGL @757toga

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! What *did* you do in that situation? There are lots of variables at both towered and non-towered airports, and if you think that you didn't make the best decision at the time then adding more details might get a better response. [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/82422/62) is fairly similar and might help too.

Comment: @pondlife I did a 360 2 miles to the west of midfield at 2,500 and by the time I finished the 360 I was able to reach tower who then instructed me to drop into the down wind I was next to

Comment: Sounds like you did the most reasonable/safe thing you could. There's no (IMO) exact answer to this question, except the usual "you should aviate, navigate, communicate"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably no perfect answer to your question because there are lots of variables. But, because ATC told you to stay at 2500 ft, I would remain at that altitude and well outside the airport area. When I'm able to contact the tower I would ask for further instructions.

By the way, if the airport/runway uses left traffic, ATC can omit the traffic pattern information (e.g. enter left downwind).

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean they can omit traffic pattern info? Isn’t standard entry into a towered airport whatever ATC instructs you to do? Or do you just mean if they say “enter downwind” to assume it’s left downwind?

Comment: @Spencer the second one, though I always specify myself. But I don't work at a super busy place where dropping the "left" will make or break my flow.

Comment: @SpencerDR The tower could just say something like "report entering downwind" (or similar). Assuming you reported that you had the ATIS. Left hand traffic can be assumed if omitted by the tower.