# How do large drones communicate with ATC?

Tags: radio-communications, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

For large drones like the [Reaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Atomics_MQ-9_Reaper), [X-47](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_X-47A_Pegasus), and aircraft like that, how do the "pilots" communicate with ATC when they need to?

Comment: they don't the guy flying it does

Comment: @ratchetfreak: By phone using only ground channels from pilot location to ATC? Or do they use the done radio?

Comment: My guess is they don't. They're usually used over foreign soil where the whole idea is that nobody knows they're there. If they're flying around the home country for training or something they probably stay within an active MOA. I don't think they're flying them around cross-country. Although it would be interesting to see one landing at LAX.

Comment: [Related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/15313/62)

Comment: "On 18 September 2014, the Triton successfully conducted an 11-hour cross-country flight from Northrop Grumman's Palmdale, California facility to Naval Air Station Patuxent River in Maryland. ... The aircraft flew a pre-approved instrument route along the southern U.S. border" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_MQ-4C_Triton#Flight_testing

Comment: All drones independent of size assuming they aren't model aircraft would have to have some means of contacting ATC such as wandering into controlled airspace.

Answer (score 7):

They have an onboard VHF radio that can be used to receive and transmit on local frequencies.

For example, on the MQ-1B Predator you will see a small fin on the back of the aircraft behind the GPS dome. That is an omni-directional antenna which can transmit VHF. The Global Hawk has a similar capability.