# What are the separation requirements on the ground?

Tags: faa-regulations, ground-operations, taxiing, separation

What are the FAA regulations for aircraft separation on the ground, outside of active runways?

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2806/how-much-is-the-minimum-safe-distance-between-two-planes-in-flight

Answer (score 8):

FAA ATC is responsible for issuing instructions in order to prevent collisions during operations on the airport's "**Movement Area**," which is defined in the FAA [Pilot/Controller Glossary](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/pcg_10-12-17.pdf) as:

> MOVEMENT AREA− The runways, taxiways, and
> other areas of an airport/heliport which are utilized
> for taxiing/hover taxiing, air taxiing, takeoff, and
> landing of aircraft, exclusive of loading ramps and
> parking areas. At those airports/heliports with a
> tower, specific approval for entry onto the movement
> area must be obtained from ATC.

There are no specific ATC distance separation requirements between aircraft on the ground (exclusive of the runways as per your question).  However, **paragraph 3-7-3** of the [FAA's JO 7110.65Z](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7110.65Z_ATC_Bsc_w_Chg_1_2_and_3_dtd_11-3-22.pdf)  (Air Traffic Control Handbook) states the following with respect to issuing **cautionary** verbiage during ground operations:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Except in relation to active runways, the FAA defines no specific minimum separation between aircraft operating on the ground.

[JO 7110.65 paragraph 2–1–1](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap2_section_1.html) states that "the primary purpose of the ATC system is to prevent a collision involving aircraft operating in the system." So ATC must issue instructions that ensure aircraft do not "trade paint" (collide) with another aircraft, a vehicle, a structure, a pedestrian, etc.

Furthermore, the ATC system is intended to "[provide] a safe, orderly, and expeditious flow of air traffic." So ATC instructions should also ensure that aircraft do not end up pointing nose-to-nose on the same piece of pavement with no way to turn around and no room to pass by each other: a "Golden Towbar Award" moment.

For pilots, [14 CFR 91.111(a)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-91/subpart-B/subject-group-ECFRe4c59b5f5506932/section-91.111) requires that "no person may operate an aircraft so close to another aircraft as to create a collision hazard."